# Object moves with bone, but I need it to pivot based on another bone

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I have a problem where in the real world a hydraulic piston (A) pushes an attached arm (B) causing it to rotate. The problem is that my yellow mesh needs to pivot at point C, however ends at point D.

Each mesh is parented to the associated bone and the bones maintain a hierachy down the line. I can't use a contraint at Point C as this restricts other movements. I have tried various bones from E to C, however nothing I try seems to work.

Any suggestions would really be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **Inverse Kinematics**
[image]

Using IK, you can still rotate other bones, and you can make the C bone a child of IK so they are separated and clean (C is in exact same place as IK bone).
The A bone stretches to the B bone, which performs the actual work
To move your system when A is moved, use **Locked Track** on B and select A tail as target, but it won't work as you wish.

Comment: Brilliant... IK was the answer. In the accepted answer, the "IK target" is a bone extruded from the "tip", hence when the IK constraint is added the chain length is 3. Dont extrude the "IK target" from the "IK" bone as I first did when implementing this answer. Thanks again.